# Symfony4 FOSRestBundle try to persist ManyToMany SQL syntax error

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, fosrestbundle, persist

I get an SQL syntax error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO group (name) VALUES (?)' with params [\"Entwickler\"]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group (name) VALUES ('Entwickler')' at line 1
```

while I try to persist an entity with a ManyToMany relation.

**Scenario**

I have an entity called `folder` and an entity called `group`. There is a ManyToMany relationship between these entities, because one group can have multiple folders, and one folder can have multiple groups.

There is already one folder with id `1`. Now I want to create a group and want to add the folder with id 1 to this group.

**Group Entity**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GroupRepository")
 */
class Group
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Folder", inversedBy="groups")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="group_folder",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="folder_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     * )
     */
    private $folder;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->folder = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Folder[]
     */
    public function getFolder(): Collection
    {
        return $this->folder;
    }

    public function addFolder(Folder $folder): self
    {
        if (!$this->folder->contains($folder)) {
            $this->folder[] = $folder;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFolder(Folder $folder): self
    {
        if ($this->folder->contains($folder)) {
            $this->folder->removeElement($folder);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Folder Entity**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FolderRepository")
 */
class Folder
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var Secret[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Secret", mappedBy="folder")
     */
    private $secrets;

    /**
     * @var Folder[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Folder", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @var Folder
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Folder", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Group", mappedBy="folder")
     */
    private $groups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->secrets = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return Secret[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getSecrets()
    {
        return $this->secrets;
    }

    /**
     * @return Folder[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * @param Folder $children
     */
    public function addChildren($children)
    {
        $this->children[] = $children;
        $children->setParent($this);
    }

    /**
     * @return Folder
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * @param Folder $parent
     */
    public function setParent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Group[]
     */
    public function getGroups(): Collection
    {
        return $this->groups;
    }

    public function addGroup(Group $group): self
    {
        if (!$this->groups->contains($group)) {
            $this->groups[] = $group;
            $group->addFolder($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeGroup(Group $group): self
    {
        if ($this->groups->contains($group)) {
            $this->groups->removeElement($group);
            $group->removeFolder($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**GroupType Form**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Folder;
use App\Entity\Group;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class GroupType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('folder', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Folder::class,
                'multiple' => true
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Group::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Controller Action which I send the POST Request to**

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return View
 *
 * @Rest\Post("/api/groups", name="api_group_create")
 */
public function CreateGroupAction(Request $request)
{
    $group = new Group();
    $form = $this->createForm(GroupType::class, $group);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($group);
        $em->flush();

        return View::create($group, 201);
    }

    return View::create($form, 400);
}
```

**The request body I send to `/api/groups`**

```
{
    "group": {
        "name": "Entwickler",
        "folder": [
            1
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried many diffenrent ways to solve that problem, but nothing works as i expected. That drives me nuts for hours now.

Comment: `group` is a reserved keyword on MySQL !! Try to rename your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mathieu Dormeval, that was the solution.

I altered the group entity definition from:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GroupRepository")
 */
class Group
```

To:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GroupRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="groups")
 */
class Group
```